# calculate box2d impulse for a certain angle of impact

Tags: iphone, objective-c, box2d

I have a ball (a dynamic body in the shape of a circle) that acts on a surface (trampoline) in the conditions of a gravity force.

When the ball impacts the trampoline (drawn in the picture from point A to B) I would like to apply an impulse (normal to the trampoline surface) to the ball.

[image]

The problem is that right now i use:

```
 b2Vec2 impulse = b2Vec2(0, [self fullMass]*[GameMaster sharedInstance].usrTrampolineForce);

 b2Vec2 impulsePoint = _body->GetWorldPoint(b2Vec2(0/PTM_RATIO, -1.0/PTM_RATIO));

 _body->ApplyLinearImpulse(impulse, impulsePoint);
```

Which sends the ball perpendicular(on the surface) up (the red direction in the drawing), although it should respect a certain realistic trajectory (drawn with black).

How can i apply the impulse to have a realistic jump?

i.e. Note that i am interested in all the cases of the ball intersection. for example, the ball could drop on the trampoline and the ball should still have a correct trajectory.

Comment: The realistic trajectory _is_ red. reflection on the normal is correct, IIRC.

Comment: @brice i have drawn the picture to make a point. Looking at the code, you can note that if this is the correct case, that means that regardless of the AB edge (the angle between the edge and the ball direction vector), every interaction between the ball and the AB edge would make the ball jump up, which is incorrect in the real world.

Comment: Got you. It's not a solid surface, but you want to actively provide an impulse to the ball when you have a collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't read objective-C, but the problem seems to be clear:

Your impulse `b2Vec2(0, [self fullMass]*[GameMaster sharedInstance].usrTrampolineForce)` does not actually include any x component!

Split your impulse into x and y components (pseudocode):

```
Impulse_magnitude = Ball_mass * Trampoline_Force
# theta is the angle between the horizontal and your impulse
# this will depend on the angle of the trampoline.
Impulse_x = Impulse_magnitude * Cos(theta)
Impulse_y = Impulse_magnitude * Sin(theta)
# Create your impulse vector
Impulse_v = b2Vec(Impulse_x, Impulse_y)
```

Comment: damn, how could i have missed the x component?! That's what happens when you copy-paste code. Thanks brice!