# create trampoline-like effect in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, game-physics

I need implement trampoline-like effect like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924640/calculate-box2d-impulse-for-a-certain-angle-of-impact) and apply a force to a body when it collides with trampoline.
But how can I detect this moment?
Or maybe can I just create a body which can't move by gravity or other bodies, but has a trampoline effect?

Comment: what have you done? give your idea a try and once you have something come back with a more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create more force than provided by restitution?

Well you can do this all.....

One way is set restitution as 0.9 or 1(of both the bodies in contact)... the other way is get those bodies by tag and then apply linearImpulse on the body you want trampoline effect....

I hope this helps